# Gplus intent sharing on Android 4.4.2

Tags: android, google-plus

I am using the below mention code to share on GPLUS. It is sharing successfully on emulator and on several other devices.

```
        Intent shareIntent = new PlusShare.Builder(ActivityDetail.this)
            .setType("text/plain")
            .setText(
                    offer.title + " - "
                            + J.Funcs.decode(offer.description_detailed))
            .setContentUrl(Uri.parse(offer.image)).getIntent();

    startActivityForResult(shareIntent, 1);
```

But the problem is, it is crashing on sharing. Any idea what I have done wrong?

Comment: post logcat................

Comment: Actually it is crashing on client device. unable to get logcat. However i've installed crashlytics in it. But it is also not showing any error.